# iTunes connect. Updating app issue

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I've just updated my iOs app. And the Itunes connection question is that:

```
Have you added or made changes to encryption features since your last submission of this app?
```

The first time I've uploaded my app I select : `my app contains encryption.`

So, now what I have to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, did you change anything about the encryption?

If 'Yes' then say 'yes', if not say 'no' - simple as that.

(If you still have the same encryption technology and use it in the same way then you say YES)